# PacketTracer .pkt file opening problem

Tags: packet-analyzer

A few days back I installed .bin packet tracer using terminal.
It got installed successfully and is opening too from the desktop icon.

Problem is when I save a .pkt file that file doesn't open.

Answer (score 1):

For the time being, I found that opening the main packet tracer and then opening the saved files by ctrl+o works....

let c, if we have any other solution